# How to Customise Week Number for Google Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

Google Calendar has a Week Number calendar that neatly adds the week numbers as little icons to my calendar. However, I want the numbers to start halfway through the year, not from January.

Is it possible to change which week is week 1 OR is it possible to make my own calendar with those little icons?

Comment: I have that Calendar as well. I don't think, having seen the settings, it is possible. I hope I'm wrong.....Welcome back on Web Applications !!

Comment: I do realise it has been many years, was just looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible natively. Here's a Chrome extension for this.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-week-number-google/fjaidefhllhbbhlfnnopcoljnhimiakp/related

This extension allows you to set a date which the first week starts on. The week number will then reflect this. Check its description in the web store for more details.

Works in Chrome/Edge (just install from the Chrome Web Store)